# Elemento não responde ao clique do Selenium (Python)

Tags: html, python, selenium-webdriver, dom

Estou há pouco tempo trabalhando com o Selenium em Python e enfrentando um problema em minha automação:

O Selenium identifica o elemento (tanto por xpath como por qualquer outra maneira), mas no momento de clicar, o elemento não se comporta da maneira esperada. Seguem 2 imagens sobre:

O que deveria acontecer:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está acontecendo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Se alguém não entendeu a pergunta, por favor me avise para que eu possa elaborá-la melhor. Estou realmente precisando dessa resposta.**

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Pelo que vi da imagem, existe o atributo `disabled="true"` no botão que deseja clicar, poderia remover a `metatag disabled` e depois de remover efetuar o clique.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que reparei, na primeira imagem o button tem um "is-loading" no final da classe, coisa que não tem na classe da segunda imagem.

Se esse for o único form com a classe "sort-request" você pode tentar algo assim:

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.Xpath, "//*[@class='sort-requests']/descedant-or-self::button");
elem.Click();
```

Eu costumo usar o Selenium em C#, o código acima escrevi baseado na documentação oficial em Python.

Comment: Então esse pode ser um erro ou até mesmo uma espécie de proteção do site. Com o Geckodriver eu tenho esse problema, com o navegador direto, não.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o expected_conditions do selenium com phyton para validar se esse elemento é clicavel. No expected_conditions você pode usar esse cara [element_to_be_clickable](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable). Já se o problema for de fato a localização do elemento tu pode localizar ele por CSS Selector, ai tu localiza o elemento de text dentro do botão. Seria mais ou menos assim:

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.send-update > text')`

Comment: O botão é clicável. Ele identifica o elemento e aparentemente TENTA clicar. Quando isso acontece, ele apenas faz um "hover" e não ocorre o evento de clique em si.